# How can I enqueue protocol relative external (//ajax.googleapis.com/...) scripts?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script), wp_enqueue_script supports protocol relative, or protocol agnostic external links: "Remote assets can be specified with a protocol-agnostic URL, i.e. '//otherdomain.com/js/theirscript.js'."

But I'm not seeing it:

```
wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false', array(), '3', true);
```

Output:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:25898//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&#038;ver=3'></script>
```

Notice that the protocol relative URL is appended to the site URL.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code you posted works fine and results in this in the HTML output:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&#038;ver=3'></script>
```

Tested on WordPress 3.5 with this code snippet:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test');
function test() {
  wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false', array(), '3', true);
}
```

Comment: Do you know it this is new in WordPress 3.5?

Comment: Protocol-relative URLs was added 7 months ago: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16560

Comment: Ok, so it's not the version of WordPress that I'm using. So what could cause the difference in behaviour?

Comment: Well, that code was added 7 months ago, but if you look at the ticket, it has a 3.5 milestone, so yes it's probably new behavior to 3.5.

Comment: Oh right, I was looking at the 'Version' field which was set to 3.1, but that's the version of WordPress at the time the ticket was created.

Comment: I think this issue occurs in 3.3.1.  Just had the same problem, upgrading to the latest fixed it.

Comment: It definitely occurs in 3.3.1, because protocol relative support was not added until 3.5. Run the latest version, always.